# Integrate server side java with a cordova app

Tags: java, web-services, cordova

How can I use java web services in a cordova app? When I include the api call using ajax, I'm getting an error: "Allow-origin-access-control". Is there a way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, you have to whitelist the domain.

In your cordova project's config.xml file add the below.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

In your index.html page, you can add the below meta information.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

To knowm ore about white-listing visit https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: I'm getting the same error after adding these, in chrome browser. Whereas, the error is gone in android emulators. How can I fix it in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of CORS. You can write a CORS filter to get it resolved.

How to write CORS filter, [click here](http://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/)

Answer (score 0):

you are doing cross domain request. Try using *JSONP* Ajax request .